# Tool-bar error message in Emacs: "better pass an explicit argument"

Tags: emacs, toolbar

I have this message at every startup of Emacs :

```
Toggling tool-bar-mode off; better pass an explicit argument.
```

It is related to this line of code in my .emacs :

```
(tool-bar-mode nil)
```

I see nothing wrong in my code. How can I fix this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nil` is the lack of a value. The message is telling you to use an actual value.

Use `(tool-bar-mode -1)` instead.

Comment: Note also that as of Emacs 24, a `nil` argument to minor modes called in code will always *enable* the mode, rather than toggle it. (Calling a minor mode interactively with no argument will still toggle it, of course.)